What's the max limit for each currency?
The game has six currencies. I just found out the "R" currency caps at 50,000.  What about the others?

 Requisition slips - 50,000
 Warbond medals - 250
 Super credits - No limit
 Common samples - 500
 Rare samples - 250
 Super samples - 100

Where did you get this information from?

"Super credits - No limit" To be a bit pedantic, surely there's a technical maximum (e.g. 2^64), even if it is completely unreachable through legitimate means.

@Stevoisiak: Sample limits here, super credits here, the rest from personal experience.
